# Create an array of arrays to feed CSV function

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I'm trying to create a CSV from a query, and I need the data to fit the following format:

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$array = array(
    array("data11", "data12", "data13"),
    array("data21", "data22", "data23"),
    array("data31", "data32", "data23"));
outputCSV($array);
```

I'm used to aggregating data like this:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $values[]   = $row['value'];
}
```

How can I pass `outputCSV` an appropriate array?

Comment: If you just want a CSV of data from MySQL, why not use [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html)?

Comment: I actually didn't know about that - pretty handy. I simplified my question though, and need to have the ability to do things with the data, so I'm not sure that's the best solution for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function outputCSV($rows, $fieldNames = array())
{
    if ($fp = fopen('php://output', 'w')) {
        if ($fieldNames) {
            fputcsv($fp, $fieldNames);
        }
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            fputcsv($fp, $row);
        }
        fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just use the `STDOUT` constant instead of opening/closing `php://output`.  See http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php

Comment: @eggyal: Do **not** use `STDOUT` as it bypasses the output buffers. Instead, use `php://output`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that!  Can you cite a reference?  All I can find is [It is recommended that you simply use the constants `STDIN`, `STDOUT` and `STDERR` instead of manually opening streams using these wrappers.](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php)

Comment: Simply see for yourself by running this in CLI: `ob_start(); echo "abc"; fwrite(STDOUT, "def"); echo ob_get_clean();`

Answer (score 1):

Loop over your `$array`, calling [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php):

```
foreach ($array as $fields) fputcsv(STDOUT, $fields);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $values[]   = $row;
}

outputCSV($values);
```